# LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE: REPLACE clause working in phpMyAdmin but not from PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The below works in PHP. I see my 'Load Successful' echo.

```
$sql = "
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'test.xml'
INTO TABLE test
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<row>'
";

if (mysqli_query($dbc, $sql)) {
    echo "Load Successful";
} else {
    echo "Load Error";
}
```

This next bit works if I submit it in the phpMyAdmin GUI:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'test.xml'
REPLACE
INTO TABLE test
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<row>'
```

Why would the below not work in PHP?? I'm getting my 'Load Error' echo.

```
$sql = "
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'test.xml'
REPLACE
INTO TABLE test
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<row>'
";


if (mysqli_query($dbc, $sql)) {
    echo "Load Successful";
} else {
    echo "Load Error";
}
```

Very confused. Clearly missing something simple. Any pointers would be much appreciated. Struggling to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an attempt to get around this, I tried first deleting everything from the table from PHP before loading data without using the replace clause.

Problem solved. The database user I was trying to execute this with did not have delete privileges.

REPLACE requires the DELETE privilege.